# PHP Returning two different times

Tags: php, wordpress, date, server, whm

Hello all I'm working on a php script that displays the wrong time.

The function I used is:

```
<?php
    echo "The time is " . date("h:i:sa");
?>
```

THat shows my time plus 6 hrs.

But when I use `<?php echo exec('date'); ?>`

It shows the correct time.

It's setup on a dedicated VPS on godaddy.  The server time in WHM is set to -6 or America/Central.

I"m using the first function to pull a custom field from a custom post type in wordpress that shows the school day for a school.  Problem is that when the clock is out 6hrs it shows the wrong school day for 12hrs a day (6hrs wrong, 12hrs right, 6hrs wrong again.).

I"ve tried setting it in PHP.ini and .htaccess.  WTF?  The entire widget code looks like this.

```
<?php 

$current_day = date('Ymd');
// args
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'schoolday',
        'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year'  => $today["year"],
            'month' => $today["mon"],
            'day'   => $today["mday"],
        ),
    )
);

// get results
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
?>
<div class="one-half first"><time datetime="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>" class="icon">

  <strong>School Day</strong>
  <span><?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <?php the_field('realschoolday'); ?></span>
</time></div><?php endwhile; ?><?php endif; ?>

<div class="one-half"><time datetime="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>" class="icon">
  <em><?php echo date('l'); ?></em>
  <strong><?php echo date('F'); ?></strong>
  <span><?php echo date('jS'); ?></span>
</time></div>

<?php
    echo "The time is " . date("h:i:sa");
?>
<br />
<?php echo exec('date'); ?>`
```

I added the last line for trouble shooting and it echos' the right time. What the #$%#.

I"m super new at php so please be kind.

Comment: date.timezone in your php.ini

Comment: `date("h:i:sa");` depents on php internal time , `exec('date');` calls the system time below that script.

Comment: Thank you my server support team didn't know the difference.  How do I adjust the php internal time?  I"ve set it in WHM, and tried .htacess and php.ini.  THank you kindly.

Comment: any luck on configuring the `php.ini`? if you don't mind can you tell us what os you used? if no luck on configuration side, you might be interested to try [date_default_timezone_set(string)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this at the top of your file `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');`

the list of supported PHP time zones here if you need another one http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php